# in spring, what's the diff between advisor and aspect?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

spring doc says advisor(not advice) is a light weight aspect. I want to know more about this two.

all information, like conception and code (spring code indeed impliment those conception) are welcome.

but I cound not find doc's to in deep explanation about this.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding..

**Aspect** means particular **concern you want to address** which cuts across your application as whole like logging , security etc..

Now **what action to take** ( at particular point cut ) is specified by **advisor**.
Like you can say 
I want to address logging aspect by putting logger statement at start of all all methods.

So you can say Aspect is concern and advisor is way to address that concern.

Comment: you mean "advice"? in spring advice is diff than advisor

Comment: @lovespring An `Advisor` provides `Advice`.